# convert non decimal string to specific decimal number in vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, decimal

So I have this :

```
dim nonDecString as string = "12"
dim decimalPlaces as integer = 2 //this value can be changed dynamically
```

What I want is to convert that nonDecString to have decimal places as "12.00" or "12.000", or "12.00n0".

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Google searched 'decimal formatting vb.net'? Please show your research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Decimal.Parse` and `Decimal.ToString`:

```
Dim dec As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(nonDecString)
Dim result = dec.ToString("N" & decimalPlaces)
```

Read: [Standard Numeric Format Strings, The numeric ("N") format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString)

> The precision specifier indicates the desired number of digits after
>   the decimal point. If the precision specifier is omitted, the number
>   of decimal places is defined by the current
>   `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits` property.